# error 400 bad request en Ajax con admin_ajax de wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, plugin

Resulta que estoy haciendo un plugin de Wordpress en el que necesito hacer un AJAX para el archivo "admin_ajax.php" de Wordpress, pero cuando envío la solicitud, el cliente me da el error 400 (bad request) y no entiendo por qué razón

[image: Request]

[image: Payload]

este es mi código

**Javascript:**

```
$.post(window.dibibot.ajax_uri, {
    action: "dibibot_check_message_read",
    to: (window.dibibot.USER_KEYS.split(":")[1]).toString(),
    message_id: JSON.stringify(data.message)
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**Ajax php function:**

```
<?php
    function dibibot_check_message_read() {
        global $wpdb;
        $conversation_guid = $_POST['to'];
        $message_id = json_decode($_POST['message_id'], true);

        $conversation = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT metadata FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "dibibot_conversations WHERE guid = '".$conversation_guid."'");
        $conversation = maybe_unserialize($conversation);
        for ($j=0; $j < count($message_id) ; $j++) { 
            for ($i=0; $i < count($conversation); $i++) {
                if($conversation[$i]['id'] == $message_id[$j]) {
                    $conversation[$i]['status'] = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $result = $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'dibibot_conversations', [ "metadata" => maybe_serialize($conversation) ], [ "guid" => $conversation_guid]);
        echo $result ? 1 : 0;
        wp_die(); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: No se si les pasa a otros. Me genera muchas dudas ese javascript y me falta información para poder ayudarte/o replicar el problema.
Podrías editar la pregunta con la información faltante?

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta declarar los hooks que harán que esa función este disponible

```
<?php 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dibibot_check_message_read', 'dibibot_check_message_readn' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dibibot_check_message_read', 'dibibot_check_message_read' );
```

Comment: No, eso ya lo tengo, solo que lo omiti al realizar esta pregunta.

Comment: Dale un console.log(window.dibibot.ajax_uri); justo antes de usarlo en el post a ver si est'a recibiendo la url correcta

Comment: Hola, si, ya lo hice. y es la url correcta.

Comment: alli deje la captura igualmente

Comment: Activa el modo debug y revisa el log a ver cual es especificamente el error que esta dando 

https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: donde activo eso? en wp_config?

Comment: Si, copia el codigo del ejemplo llamado: Example wp-config.php for Debugging
Esto permitira que se guarde un archivo debug.log dentro de la carpeta wp-content

Comment: gracias, no sabia eso. pude corregir ademas otros errores. pero mientras tanto, me causa este error con respecto a esta pregunta.

Comment: `[29-Aug-2018 18:09:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\DiBi-Bot\ajax.php on line 194` Que crees que puede ser. La linea 194 representa el `for` de la variable `$message_id`

Comment: Prueba quitando el json_decode.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82432/discussion-between-hv-sombrilla-and-anthony-medina).